# I was wondering of this is a scam

Tags: bank-account

A woman told me she is going to put money in my account and wants my login username and password. Is this real or should I say no?

Comment: if anyone anywhere ever asks for your password it is a scam (or they are incompetent).

Comment: One thing to do in situations like this is to say it out loud and listen to yourself.  Do that three times and you should have the answer.

Comment: You shouldn't even say no. This is so clearly a scam, and you want to avoid any contact with that scammer. Don't reply at all.

Answer (score 4):

**You should say No**

Frankly I'd be suspicious enough I'm not sure I'd even give her the legit details to send money properly.

You can't actually transfer money into a bank account *from* that bank account. 
She should only ever need your sort code and account number to send money to you!

There are exactly two possibilities here:

> It's a scam and she's going to steal all your money

Or

> She doesn't understand how bank accounts work

There is absolutely no reason she would need your login details and nobody should ever need them except you.

Comment: This. Lets be honest, it's never the 2nd option unless the other party is like 70+ maybe and even then. If they really want to give you money they only need your bank account and sometimes your name (and maybe some code to identify your bank but this will depend on your country I guess).

Comment: You should not do this even if she doesn't ask for the password. The answer should reflect this, because otherwise the OP might reply that a password is not required and then the scammer might say *"OK, fine, then give me only your account number, and not the password"*, and from then on it's a classic wire transfer scam.